# Problems creating cool downs

Tags: python, discord.py

I created some commands, but since I do not want to have more spam / flood, I try to make a cool down. But I get frequent errors, also I don’t understand how to make a cool down specifically for the participant, and not for the whole server  .Please, help!

Comment: This is not possible to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve that by storing in a List of Tuples the association of the member.id and the last time the member sent a command.

You have to define:

- a variable 'cooldown' (for eg: `cooldown = 30000` in milliseconds)
- a list of member.id/last message (eg: `list= [('member1id','1592382596'),('member2id','1592382598')]

Then each time the method `@discord_client.event async def on_message(message):` is triggered you check if it is a command and after you check the `list`. You retrieve the last message for time for the current member and check if it didn't exceed `cooldown`.

To get current time you can use:

```
import calendar;
import time;
current_time = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
```

To check if cooldown has been exceed:

```
current_time - time_from_list > cooldown
```

If true the user is able to do the command so you execute the associated method.
Then you should update the list.